# $a_1 = 1, a_{n + 1} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}a_n.$ does this sequence converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider the sequence that is defined recursively by $a_1 = 1, a_{n + 1} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}a_n.$ does this sequence converge and if so, to what? Prove it.

**My answer is**

since $a_2 = 1 + \frac{1}{2}, a_3 = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}, a_4 = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} \dots$

Then yes the sequence converges and $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^k}$ and hence it is a finite geometric series and its sum is 2, am I correct?

Comment: _Presumably_, you are meant to argue that it converges by way of "monotone and bounded", before you start calculations on what the limit actually is. That's usually the way these problems go. Not that your order of doing things is wrong. I just suspect it's not intended. Some times, calculations can show a limit value even though the sequence doesn't actually converge.

Comment: So, what should I do?@Arthur

Comment: @Arthur under the assumption that he already knows the geometric series converges then his method works, there is no need to show it is monotone and bounded here using his method

Comment: @Lorago As I said, I don't think the approach here is wrong in this case. It's just something to look out for. Some examples can be quite subtle. It isn't too difficult to find problems that look more or less just like this where only some initial values yield convergence.

Comment: Alt. hint: $\,a_{n + 1} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}a_n \iff a_{n+1}-2 = \frac{1}{2}(a_n-2)\,$ so $\,a_n-2\,$ is a geometric progression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be a bit more rigorous about proving that

$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^k}$$

using, for example, a simple induction argument, but other than that it looks fine. If you don't, for some reason, notice this pattern immediately, you could also show that the sequence in increasing and bounded above by, for example, $2$. Then it converges by a well known result. Then, to find the limit, simply take the limit of both sides of the recursion formula. If we denote the limit by $a$, then it becomes

$$a=1+\frac{1}{2}a\iff a=2.$$

The reason I show this method is because it is a more general approach that often works well for this type of problems, but your method of course works great here.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is ok but you can have a more general solution process if you recognise that this is a linear difference equation with constant coefficients.

The more general equation $a_{n+1}-\frac 12 a_n = f_n$ (in this particular case you have $f_n=1$ can be written as $a_n = a_{h,n} + a_{p,n}$, where $a_{h,n}$ is the general solution of the homogeneous equation $a_{n+1}-\frac 12 a_n = 0$ (in this particular case, $a_{h,n} = c (1/2)^n$) and a particular solution of the complete equation (in this case $a_{p,n} = 2$ is a constant particular solution). It should be noted that for more general $f_n$ it may be less trivial to guess the general expression for $a_n$ using your process.

The general solution is $a_n = c(1/2)^n +2$. The initial condition leads to $c = -2$, which means that $a_n= -(1/2)^{n-1} + 2$.

Now you see that the solution is a convergent sequence with $\lim a_n = 2$.